# How can I call a function that returns a promise for each item array in a loop

Tags: angular, for-loop, promise, ionic3, angular5

```
public takePicture() { 
 let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 };
    return this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
      .then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
          return this.beforeSave(data[i].fullPath).then((save) => {
            this.save(save);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err: CaptureError) => { console.log(err) });
}
```

I am trying for each image that I am taking from my camera to phone to call the beforeSave(). However, only for the first one, the promise is returned. How should I implement my code in order to do it for each item in my data array?

Comment: Do you think `Promise.all` can help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @AliF50 can u please give an example?

Comment: Oh, you're returning right away, okay, let me try. Try removing the `return` keyword like I have in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal here is to save all images that were captured and communicate back completion or error to the caller then you can change to a `.map()` to collect an array of promises and use `Promise.all()` to monitor that array of promises.  That code looks like this:

```
public takePicture() { 
    let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 };
    return this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options).then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        // collect array of promises and use Promise.all() to monitor them
        return Promise.all(data.map(item => {
            return this.beforeSave(item.fullPath).then((save) => {
              return this.save(save);
            });
        }));
    }).catch((err: CaptureError) => { 
        // log error, then rethrow so caller can see the error
        console.log(err) 
        throw err;
    });
}
```

FYI, this assumes your use of `this.beforeSave()` and `this.save()` is correct.  I don't know these interfaces so I'm just taking your lead on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning right away and the for loop does not complete. Try removing the `return`.

```
public takePicture() { 
 let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 };
    return this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
      .then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          this.beforeSave(data[i].fullPath).then((save) => { // !! Remove the return here
            this.save(save);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err: CaptureError) => { console.log(err) });
}
```

Comment: Also, it should be `i < data.length`

Comment: Answers with zero explanation can be improved by explaining what you changed and why without leaving us to have to do our own visual diff.

Comment: A problem with this approach is that it does not handle errors in the `this.beforeSave()` promise chain or in `this.save()`.  It ignores those errors and could even end with an `unhandledRejection`.  Further, it doesn't propagate errors back to the caller or let the caller know when everything is done.  I think your first comment about using `Promise.all()` is probably what this needs.

Comment: @jfriend00 can u suggest a better solution?

Comment: @AliF50 this takes time to call the save() why?

Comment: It should be calling `save` after each promise `(this.beforeSave(data[i].fullPath))` resolves. As far as it taking time, it can be anything from the API to your internet speed. As far as doing the `Promise.all` approach or what not, yes sure, it can be better but I don't know if you're consuming `takePicture` in an asynchronous way so I don't know if `Promise.all` will be better. I can't look at a small sample and conclude that this way or that way is better without looking at the bigger picture. The simple mistake was `return`ing right away from the function, the rest is up to you.